# Are PendingIntent names for sms aribtrary?

Tags: android, sms

Pretty much all the examples I find for sending an SMS message define the strings

```
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
```

where PendingIntents are formed like this:

```
PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast (this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
PendingIntent deliveryIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast (this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED0), 0);
```

ultimately for the calls

```
sms.sendTextMessage (phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
```

or (using an array of them)

```
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage (phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveredIntents);
```

Are these strings arbitrary?  The best I can tell is that you simply need to filter for them in your BroadcastReceiver, but it doesn't matter what the actual strings are.  Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's true, since you are actually creating the Intent, all you have to do is to make sure that the action specified in the Intent matches the one in the IntentFilter when creating your broadcast receiver.
You should take on count that a pending intent has internally no difference from a regular intent, except that will be executed after some time and even when application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it

This is the important part of them taken from android documentation:

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.
>
> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

But going back to your question, you can specify any action without any problem as long as the action do not match other actions registered for another broadcastreceiver and even so, it should match in action as well as meta data, so chances that something like that happen are quiet low
Hope this Helps..

Regards!

Comment: Ok, cool.  However, then wouldn't it be a good idea to use more unique strings?  How do I know that some other app isn't using the same strings and, thus, receiving my notifications as well.  Or, vice versa?

Comment: Simple, if your action matches any other action specified in any other application the OS itself will show a message, "you might already seen it when trying to see a video for example" it asks you what application should handle that action e.g YouTube or Browser, although is a little harder than just that, because usually android internal intents contain metadata and that should match exactly in order to consider it as same intent...

Comment: Don't get me wrong but if the answer is what you were looking for would be nice if you mark it as correct, so next time people might take time to answer your questions... Regards!

Comment: No worries.  SO makes me wait about 10 minutes before I can accept an answer :)

Comment: Ah, so if there is ambiguity, the user gets to choose which activity receives the intent.  Yes, I have seen that, although in the cases you mention it's for creating a new activity rather than receiving a broadcast.

Comment: No, receivers will just execute their onReceive method in each app, what I'm talking about is activities indeed...

Comment: So, in the SMS confirmation case, then one *should* use a unique string?

Comment: Whatever you want, as long as the IntentFilter has the same action, if is not unique nothin happens, the worse is that another broadcastreceiver executes its onReceive method, nothing else...